# How to store request data and reponse data into database in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on to store request data and response data if there any exceptions encountered while sending response back to client I need to store the exception also.

**My DB table** will ID,RequestData,ResponseData,Exception,TimeTakenToRespond

lets say I have endpoint called /athenticateUser so my input data would be

```
RequestData :{"username":"mate","password":"swamy"}

ResponseData :{"FirstName":"mate","LastName":"swamy","Email":"manteswamy@gmail.com"}
```

Like the above way I need to store all the request data and response data if any exception while sending response back to client that also we need store and the web service  time taken respond.

As I am beginner to spring boot please guide step by step

Answer (score 2):

Though you can write  `Interceptors`, `Filters` etc for this. But don't do it.

Please try to use Spring Boot feature `Actuator` for tracing. It provides HTTP request logging out of the box.

There's an endpoint mapped to `/trace` or `/actuator/httptrace` which will show you last 100 HTTP requests. You can customize it to log each request, or write to a DB.

You will need `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency.

You can also `whitelist` endpoints.

For the guide step by step, you can check [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/actuator-endpoints-example/) actuator tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `spring boot actuator httptrace`..

add below dependency:

```
 implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
```

Look at this [step by step guide](https://www.sedooe.com/2017/08/tracing-requests-and-responses-with-spring-boot-actuator/)..

Answer (score 1):

The Spring-boot actuator doesn't support getting the request/response bodies, they even [removed some mechanisms to do it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12953).

[Here's a blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20201020143832/http://slackspace.de/articles/log-request-body-with-spring-boot/) on how to do it with a `Filter`.